# C# Late Binding and dynamic keyword won't work together

Tags: c#, dynamic, reflection, late-binding

I'm trying to follow the examples on the book Pro C# 5.0, and I've stumbled upon one that I cannot make work:

```
static void Main() {

    Assembly asm = Assembly.Load("CarLibrary");

    Type MiniVan = asm.GetType("CarLibrary.MiniVan");

    dynamic d = Activator.CreateInstance(Minivan);

    Console.WriteLine("Type of d is {0}", d.GetType()); // Type is CarLibrary.MiniVan

    MethodInfo m = MiniVan.GetMethod("TurboBoost");
    m.Invoke(d, null); // This works fine, and prints out "Turbo Boosting"

    d.TurboBoost(); // This doesn't work like the book says it should. 
                    // I get: object does not contain a definition for TurboBoost;
```

Here's the declaration of CarLibrary:

```
namespace CarLibrary {

    // UPDATE: I just realized that I had declared MiniVan internal
    internal MiniVan {

        public void TurboBoost() {

            Console.WriteLine("Turbo Boosting");
        }
    }
}
```

So, even though MiniVan is declared as INTERNAL, using Reflection I can still create an instance of MiniVan, and make a call to TurboBoost(). But if I use the dynamic keyword, a call to TurboBoost() doesn't work. If MiniVan is declared PUBLIC though, both cases work perfectly.

Could someone tell me if all that is as it's suppose to be?

Comment: You can access private members with reflection (you can adjust the behaviour using `BindingFlags`). So yes, everything is OK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`dynamic` respects the accessibility rules, which includes not just the member's accessibility, but also whether the object's type is `internal`, `private` (nested), etc. `dynamic` is not *just* a wrapper around reflection - it is more: *would this have worked in regular C# from here*.

Which means that the same use of `dynamic` *executed inside the `CarLibrary` assembly*, would have worked. If you want to access type-members via `dynamic`, then it must be `public`, or at a minimum: accessible in the calling context.

In particular, this prevents you from cheating the runtime by accessing `public` members of `internal` types that you were *never supposed to know about directly*. For example, suppose a core CLI type implements some interface:

```
public ISomeInterface {...}
internal SomeMicrosoftType : ISomeInterface
{
    public void FireTheMissiles() {...}
}
```

Now; there may well be an API that exposes that object *as an `ISomeInterface` instance* - so we could legitimately have a reference to an object of that. In our regular code, we could have accessed members of `ISomeInterface`, but we would not have been able to call `FireTheMissiles`. However, if what you are suggesting *worked*, then we could do:

```
ISomeInterface innocent = ...
dynamic evil = innocent;
evil.FireTheMissiles();
```

Now, *yes* we can do that via *reflection*, but reflection has additional checks, especially if we aren't running with full trust.